# Open Drop Down from Middle of Button

Tags: javascript, css, button, dojo

I am designing (or attempting to) a mapping application and have a dojo.fx.toggler function that I need to display centered beneath the button. The default seems to be to open from the left. However, because of the placement of my button it runs off the edge of the page causing the user to need to scroll to see all content.

I've tried basic CSS styling to attempt this to no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the dojo.fx.Toggler toggles existing elements and doesn't create any, it seems the problem is how you have positioned the element in the first place. You should just shift the element to the right:

```
#toggledElementId
{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd vote you up if I had the 15 rep needed. I had the position set to absolute so it wouldn't move horizontally